# How to set background color of gridview cell using xml or java but it's not custom

Tags: java, android, gridview

```
public class Rajesh extends Activity {

    ListView ap;

    ListView paypalList;
    GridView gridBox;
 DisplayAppListArrayAdapter displayAppListArrayAdapter;

    Button turnOverButton;
    String[] solutionArray = { "$0.001", "$0.010", "$0.005", "$0.003", "$0.002", "$0.008", "$0.001","$0.001", "$0.001" };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    redeemTextUpper = new String[] {

                getString(R.string.get_for_500),
                getString(R.string.get_for_1000)
                };


        pics = new Integer[] {
                R.drawable.paypal, R.drawable.paypal,

        };

        appList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.appList);
        paypalList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_paypal);
        gridBox=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridFit);        
        turnOverButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOver)
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOU want turnOver!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        // gridBox.setAdapter(new TextAdapter(this));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, solutionArray);
            gridBox.setAdapter(adapter);
          //  gridBox.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18A608"));
            gridBox.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        gridBox.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18A608"));

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "

+solutionArray[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
          //  gridBox.getChildAt(9).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18A608"));
            displayAppListArrayAdapter = new DisplayAppListArrayAdapter(
                     getApplicationContext(), pics, redeemTextUpper ,null);

             paypalList.setAdapter(displayAppListArrayAdapter);





     }



    }
```

when I use this code then the background color has change but when I click but I want to change `oncreate()`.

Comment: For that you need to make a custom layout and apply a background to custom layout UI.

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to do that.

1) Create custom  `ArrayAdapter` by extending  `ArrayAdapter`.

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, solutionArray) { 
    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        int color = 0x00FFFFFF; // Transparent
        if (someCondition) { 
            color = 0xFF0000FF; // Opaque Blue
        } 

        view.setBackgroundColor(color);

        return view;
    } 
};
```

2) which is simple that above way. Just create Custom `Textview` layout and replace that layout with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` which is very easy.
Like:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:background="#18A608" />
```

I suggest if just want to change color that go for second Method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it on create, then set the color changing code in `onCreate()`, after you set the adapter:

```
gridBox.setAdapter(adapter);
int count = gridBox.getCount();
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    gridBox.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#18A608"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Post your XML, In yout XML file after define

```
   <GridView 
    android:background="@android:color/your color"></GridView>
```